# Access a column field property of advanced datagrid in the header renderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, advanceddatagrid

I have to access the column field property of an advance datagrid in the header renderer.
    Basically what i am trying to achieve is that whenever i click on a column header field then its corresponding column field can be fetched like an alert for example.

Below is my advanced datagrid grouped columns code:-

```
    <mx:groupedColumns>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Category"  sortable="false" headerWordWrap="true" wordWrap="true" width="150"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup id="dgSampleGridGroup" headerText="Student" fontFamily="Arial" backgroundColor="0xd7e9f8" childrenDragEnabled="false">

    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn  dataField="Name"  sortable="false" headerWordWrap="true" wordWrap="true"  headerRenderer="customHeaderRenderer"/>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Branch" sortable="false" headerWordWrap="true" wordWrap="true"/>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="RollNumber" sortable="false"  wordWrap="true"/>

    </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
    </mx:groupedColumns>
```

Below is the header renderer that i have used:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
        <mx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import flash.net.navigateToURL;

                import mx.controls.Alert;

                override public function set data( value:Object ) : void {
                    super.data = value;
                } 

                protected function linkbutton1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    Alert.show("Column 1:Student Name");        
                     Alert.show("Group Header",this.parentDocument.groupHeader); 
                }

            ]]>
        </mx:Script>

        <mx:LinkButton label="Student Name"  click="linkbutton1_clickHandler(event)" width="50"/>

    </mx:HBox>
```

Here i have simply hardcoded the alert with the column header name.
    I want to fetch the column header field so that i can reuse the header renderer for all the columns.
    Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set id of Data Grid Column like

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="colName"  dataField="Name"  sortable="false" headerWordWrap="true" wordWrap="true"  headerRenderer="customHeaderRenderer"/>
```

and then access colName.headerText.

this should work, feel free to ask any question.